# Using NSProgessIndicator as playback bar

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift

I am currently writing a music playing program for OS X. I am implementing an `NSProgessIndicator` to show the current playback progress of a song as it plays. How can I efficiently update the progress once per second without getting off-sync with the music?

Ideally I want something like iTunes has where it also has numbers to show the exact playback time and time remaining:
[image: iTunes Playback]

Currently the only thing I can think of is to use an `NSTimer` with the interval set 1 second and force it run on the main thread through that. However, this seems very inefficient and also like it might not keep perfect sync. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I don't think that a) it's inefficient since 1 seconds is nothing for such an update loop and b) it will likely not run out of sync for just a couple of minutes.

Comment: Are you sure a NSProgressIndicator is the right class here? A NSScrollBar might actually be more appropriate, as those already have mouse behavior.

Comment: `NSScrollBar`s can be modified, so you can use them for scrubbing... probably a better idea.

Comment: @duskwuff @SevenBits Interacting with the bar, including scrubbing, isn't going to be possible because of the nature of the media source. Excluding interactivity, is there any other reason to use `NSScrollBar` over `NSProgessIndicator`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timer just to update the info, in this case the audio current time. AVAudioPlayer has a property with the same name currentTime which will return the time for you as NSTimeInterval(seconds).